# Urn Problem: select a particular ball in a sample, without replacement

Tags: probability

> An urn has $N$ balls. A sample, without replacement, of size $n$ is taken from this urn. Determine the probability that a particular ball is selected in this sample.

**Attempt:**

The probability of NOT selecting the particular ball in the first attempt is $(N-1)/N$. Given that, the probability of not selecting the particular ball in the second attempt is $(N-2)/(N-1)$. Continuing in this fashion, we obtain:

$$P(\text{Not selecting the ball in the sample of size } n) = \frac{N-1}{N} \times \frac{N-2}{N-1} \times \cdots \times \frac{N-n}{N-n+1}$$

Now we take the complement:

$$ P(\text{Selecting the ball in the sample of size } n) = 1 - \frac{N-1}{N} \times \frac{N-2}{N-1} \times \cdots \times \frac{N-n}{N-n+1} $$

I believe my solution is correct. The official answer is $n/N$, but I can't get to that simple form. I was wondering if anyone could provide a simplification of my answer, or provide another solution that gets directly to $n/N$. I'm sure the hypergeometric distribution comes in somewhere.

Comment: You have some formating error. Please fix it so that is more readable.

Comment: Your solution is correct because it is indeed equal to $n/N$... It simplifies to $1-(N-n)/N = n/N$.

Comment: If I read this correctly, you are correct. Just notice that the product is telescopic so it simplifies to $\frac{N-n}{N}$.

Comment: @ECL Could you show how this simplification is done?

Comment: Note that $N-1$ shows up in a nominator and a denominator, so these cancel each other. The same holds for $N-2,\dots,N-n+1$. Thus you are left with $1 - \frac{N-n}{N}$.